# Phone book application how do I store a key with multiple value?

Tags: python

I need help storing a key with more than one value. I am trying to assign a name to more than one phone number but I'm having trouble doing so this is my code so far and it only stores in one phone number for one name. How do I make it so that it stores multiple phone numbers for a given name.

```
while True:
    try:
        command_input = int(input("1 search, 2 add, 3 quit:"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Command")
    else:
        if command_input == 1:
            name_input = input("Name:").casefold()
            if name_input in name_number_dictionary:
                print(name_number_dictionary[name_input])
            else:
                print("Name not found")
                
        elif command_input == 2:
            name_input = input("Name:").casefold()
            phone_input = input("Phone number:").casefold()
            name_number_dictionary[name_input] = phone_input
            
        elif command_input == 3:
            print("quitting. . . ")
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `set`

```
    elif command_input == 2:
        name_input = input("Name:").casefold()
        phone_input = input("Phone number:").casefold()
        if name_input not in name_number_dictionary:
            name_number_dictionary[name_input] = set()
        name_number_dictionary[name_input].append(phone_input)
```

When you search by the name, the whole list will be printed